# Creating an alias for Gmail, only shown SMTP option

Tags: gmail, smtp

I am trying to create a new Gmail alias so that my sending email goes with the email identity I am trying to use.

In the past, I could go to Setting -> Alias, and just verify that I own the domain to be able to set up my foo@example.com so that when I send email, it will go as that.

I tried to do that but now I am only presented with the SMTP options to send as a specified email.

Am I missing a step or has Google changed this function, and if so is there is a workaround?